# What length and gauge screw to attach a 2x4 fence rail to a 4x4 post (face screwed)?

Tags: screws, fence, hardware

I'm constructing a picket fence and need to attach the 2x4 rails to the 4x4 posts. I've seen some conflicting information of what length and gauge. I'm leaning towards 3" #9 screws. This will allow 1.5" inches in to the 4x4. Is this enough? Should I use 3 1/2 instead? How important is the gauge?

Comment: I used 3" screws for that exact same scenario and nothing's fallen apart yet (4+ years). In my experience, you'll have to search pretty hard to find a 3" screw that's _not_ a #9. Generally the smaller the screw, the narrower, and the longer the fatter. If you want, say, a 3" #10 - you're going to have to go to a specialty place, not your local big-box HIC.

Comment: With screws I usually use 3” also nails 3-1/2 shorter may be ok I’ve just done that way for many years.